# Running dir2ogg from php script

Tags: php, shell, mp3, ogg

I am trying to write a php script where it will take an uploaded mp3 file and automatically create a copy of it in ogg format.  My idea is to use exec() or shell_exec() to run dir2ogg from php.  This is my code:

```
$command = 'dir2ogg /var/www/bais-mordechai-laravel/public/uploads/"'.$filename.'"';
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

The output that I am getting from this is only the first line of the expected output:

```
dir2ogg 0.11.8 (2009-08-04), converts audio files into ogg vorbis.
```

When I run this directly from the command line (as root user) I get the following:

```
dir2ogg 0.11.8 (2009-08-04), converts audio files into ogg vorbis.

INFO: Converting "/var/www/bais-mordechai-laravel/public/uploads/Track 02.mp3" (using mpg123 as decoder)...
[wav.c:371] warning: Cannot rewind WAV file. File-format isn't fully conform now.
Encoding standard input to 
         "/var/www/bais-mordechai-laravel/public/uploads/Track 02.ogg" 
at quality 3.00
    Encoding [ 0m15s so far] / [wav.c:371] warning: Cannot rewind WAV file. File-format     isn't fully conform now.


Done encoding file "/var/www/bais-mordechai-laravel/public/uploads/Track 02.ogg"

File length:  3m 50.0s
Elapsed time: 0m 15.7s
Rate:         14.6600
Average bitrate: 91.1 kb/s
```

So it seems that the function is returning before the command is finished executing.

I thought that perhaps the script finished on its own, but there is no ogg file created as I intend.

So my question is how do I get this to work, or how can I go about debugging this?

UPDATE:
Using Mehran's advice, here is my stderr output:

```
Array
(
[stdout] => dir2ogg 0.11.8 (2009-08-04), converts audio files into ogg vorbis.


[stderr] => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dir2ogg", line 673, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/bin/dir2ogg", line 641, in main
conf = read_opts()
  File "/usr/bin/dir2ogg", line 120, in read_opts
in_path = [prefix for prefix in os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep) if os.path.exists(os.path.join(prefix, command))]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PATH'

[return] => 1
)
```

Comment: What happens when you run your PHP as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind your problem is specific to your system as I can easily run your code and generate the .ogg file. Here's what I get when I run a php file with your code in it:

```
dir2ogg 0.11.8 (2009-08-04), converts audio files into ogg vorbis.

INFO: Converting "/home/mehran/001.mp3" (using mpg123 as decoder)...
```

And as I said before the `001.ogg` is successfully created. Whatever is going on with your execution is specific to your configuration. The way to debug it is to get and print the `stderr` of the process. Here's how you can get it (`shell_exec` and `exec` functions do not give you that):

```
<?php
function _pipeExec($cmd, $input = '')
{
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, array(0 => array('pipe', 'r'), 1 => array('pipe', 'w'), 2 => array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $rtn = proc_close($proc);
    $result = array(
        'stdout' => $stdout
        , 'stderr' => $stderr
        , 'return' => $rtn
    );
    return $result;
}

$command = 'dir2ogg /home/mehran/"001.mp3"';
$output = _pipeExec($command);
print_r($output);
```

You can find more information on [proc_open here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). But the short description is that it does what exactly you want, it gives you all the outputs one process produces. In my computer the above code generates:

```
Array
(
    [stdout] => dir2ogg 0.11.8 (2009-08-04), converts audio files into ogg vorbis.

INFO: Converting "/home/mehran/001.mp3" (using mpg123 as decoder)...

    [stderr] => [wav.c:371] warning: Cannot rewind WAV file. File-format isn't fully conform now.
Encoding standard input to 
         "/home/mehran/001.ogg" 
at quality 3.00

    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m00s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m01s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m02s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m03s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m04s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m05s so far] / 
    Encoding [ 0m05s so far] - 
    Encoding [ 0m05s so far] \ 
    Encoding [ 0m05s so far] | 
    Encoding [ 0m05s so far] / [wav.c:371] warning: Cannot rewind WAV file. File-format isn't fully conform now.

    Encoding [ 0m05s so far] - 

Done encoding file "/home/mehran/001.ogg"

    File length:  3m 13.0s
    Elapsed time: 0m 05.1s
    Rate:         37.8620
    Average bitrate: 110.9 kb/s


    [return] => 0
)
```

You can use the `return` value to check for the success of the process, and as you can see even the progress indicator is also printed. Nevertheless, you can look into `stderr` and find what's wrong with your code.

**[UPDATE]**

Unfortunately, I can not replicate your error. I just tried to do what you are trying to do and faced a problem of my own I thought it's worth sharing. Here's my complete, working code to upload and convert an audio file:

```
<?php

function _pipeExec($cmd, $input = '')
{
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, array(0 => array('pipe', 'r'), 1 => array('pipe', 'w'), 2 => array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $rtn = proc_close($proc);
    $result = array(
        'stdout' => $stdout
        , 'stderr' => $stderr
        , 'return' => $rtn
    );
    return $result;
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="./ogg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="music" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_FILES['music'])) {
    $des = $_FILES['music']['tmp_name'] .'.'. pathinfo($_FILES['music']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    rename($_FILES['music']['tmp_name'], $des);
    $command = 'dir2ogg "' . $des . '"';
    $output = _pipeExec($command);
    echo "<div style='height: 500px; overflow: auto;'><pre>";
    print_r($output);
    echo "</pre></div>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The part which if you omit will result in a problem is:

```
$des = $_FILES['music']['tmp_name'] .'.'. pathinfo($_FILES['music']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
rename($_FILES['music']['tmp_name'], $des);
```

This will rename the temporary uploaded file so it will have the same extension as its original filename, i.e. it will append `.mp3` to the uploaded file. Without this I couldn't convert the file to an `.ogg` file.

One more thing regarding your error, make sure that the file you are uploading is compatible with `dir2ogg` as I have read in some of the posts here and there that some formats are not compatible and thus `dir2ogg` outputs errors like yours.

In the end, make sure that your file's size does not exceeds your upload size and/or post size limits. A `phpinfo()` will prompt you your current `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Perhaps your file is not uploaded at all! You can make sure of your successful file upload by looking into the `$_FILES['music']['error']`.

That's all I've got!

Comment: Thank you.  Now I am able to see my the error being thrown.  I added the output to my question.

Comment: Your answer lead me to a solution.  See my follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324027/why-are-python-environment-variables-different-when-executed-from-a-web-server

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this;

```
$command = 'dir2ogg /var/www/bais-mordechai-laravel/public/uploads/"'.$filename.'"';
exec ("$command 2>&1", $convert_output, $return_val);
if(preg_match("/Done/i", $convert_output[10])) {
    echo "Convert complete";
} else {
    echo "Conversion error";
    exit;
}
```

Key points in my point;

1. 2>&1 redirects command output to console, so it assigned to
   `$convert_output` line by line
2. I have lokked at your output, and result keyword exists on line **10**,
   "**Done encoding....**". So you can regex find by using keyword "**Done**"
   on ine **10**
3. Last thing, you will not get output until conversion finished

You can also check result output by;

```
var_dump(array($convert_output, $return_val));
```