# convert any audio file to ogg without ffmpeg in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, html5-audio

I am building a audio site using php. sadly bluehost and hostgator dont support ffmpeg and FF low virsion dont support mp3.
So, anybody know how to convert any audio file ogg without ffmpeg?

Comment: [**look at this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152540/running-dir2ogg-from-php-script/21214229#21214229)

Comment: You can still use `ffmpeg`, and you don't have to use what's supplied by your host. Just go to the [FFmpeg download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page and get a Linux build of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: thnx @LordNeckbeard. there is 5 downloads. which one I need? and how to work with it?

Comment: i using win 7 x64. and dont know which bit hosting provider using!

Comment: You'll have to investigate it yourself or ask your host.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to clarify your question. You cannot convert audio to `ogg` same way as you cannot convert your audio to `avi` or `mp4`. OGG is a container format, same as avi/mkv/flv/mp4; you can store your audio in OGG, but you cannot encode into it.

Most likely what you're looking for is converting your audio into **vorbis** format, and store it in ogg container. This could be done without ffmpeg; for Windows check OggEnc from http://www.rarewares.org/ogg.php - it is free software.